# Plot only reaches the middle of the Y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw a stacked barplot with the simple following plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=PKN1, y='', x=Stadium)) +
geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

However, the plots end somewhere in the middle of the y-axis.

[image: Stacked barplot]
How to change it so that they are full-length along the y-axis?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Remove `y=''` from `aes()` and use `geom_bar(position = "fill")`

Comment: @MartinC.Arnold You may post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `stat = "identity"` requires a `y` aesthetic. You don't need that here – `x = stadium` is sufficient:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill = PKN1, x = Stadium)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```